# Need help for array field

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

This script works fine for me:

```
<script>
calculate = function(){

    var resources = document.getElementById('a1').value;
    var minutes = document.getElementById('a2').value; 
    document.getElementById('a3').value = parseInt(resources)* parseInt(minutes);


} 
</script>

<form action="ProvideMedicinProcess.php" class="register" method="POST">
           <table id="dataTable"  border="1">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" required="required" name="chk[]" checked="checked" /></td>
                    <td><input type="datetime-local" required="required" name="VisitDate[]"></td>
                    <td>

                        <input class="form-control"type="text" required="required" placeholder="Symptoms" name="Symptoms[]">
                     </td>

                    <td>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" required="required"  placeholder="GivenMedicin" name="GivenMedicin[]">
                     </td>

                    <td>
                        <input id="a1" class="form-control" type="text" required="required" placeholder="UnitePrice" name="UnitePrice[]" onblur="calculate()" >
                     </td>

                    <td>
                        <input id="a2" class="form-control" type="text" required="required" placeholder="Quentity" name="Quentity[]" onblur="calculate()" >
                     </td>

                    <td>
                        <input id="a3" class="form-control" type="text" required="required" placeholder="SubTotal" name="SubTotal[]" >
                     </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

        <input type="button" value="Add" onClick="addRow('dataTable')" /> 
        <input type="button" value="Remove" onClick="deleteRow('dataTable')"  /> 
        <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Confirm" />
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $PatientIDSearch ?>" name="PatientIDSearch" />
</form>
```

But I need to calculate All Subtotal

Comment: try using jQuery and traverse all the fields you want, and add them together.

Comment: @VladimirDespotovic: Why would you need jQ to do that? You can traverse elements in vanillaJS all the same...

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Because you can! jQuery makes everything better. No JavaScript-related topic is complete until jQuery is recommended by someone. jQuery! jQuery! jQuery! No thinking required!

Comment: @AntonSamsonov: For a second there I thought you were serious :D

Comment: I never heard of vanillaJS before, I use jQuery all the time though :)

Comment: @AntonSamsonov haha, exactly! I have my brain for a lot of things, I am saving it with jQuery. jQuery rules! :)

Comment: @VladimirDespotovic: VanillaJS is just _"plain JS"_, no toolkits or frameworks. It's jokingly presented as a framework, but if you check all the boxes (of features), you'll notice the source file is still 0 bytes in size: [vanilla-js site](http://vanilla-js.com/). jQ is written in JS, so it stands to reason that anything jQ does, JS can do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some issues:

- If you add rows, you'll have to avoid that you get duplicate `id` property values in your HTML. It is probably easiest to just remove them and identify the `input` elements via their names, which does not have to be unique
- It is bad practice to assign to a non-declared variable. Use `var`, and in the case of functions, you can just use the `function calculate() {` syntax.
- Make the subtotal `input` elements read-only by adding the `readonly` attribute, otherwise the user can change the calculated total.
- Instead of responding on `blur` events, you'll get a more responsive effect if you respond to the `input` event. And I would advise to bind the event handler via JavaScript, not via an HTML attribute.
- I would fix some spelling errors in your elements (but maybe they make sense in your native language): Quantity with an 'a', UnitPrice without the 'e'.

You can use `querySelectorAll` to select elements by a CSS selector, and then `Array.from` to iterate over them.

See below snippet with 2 rows:

```js
function calculate(){
    var unitPrices = document.querySelectorAll('[name=UnitPrice\\[\\]]');
    var quantities = document.querySelectorAll('[name=Quantity\\[\\]]');
    var subTotals = document.querySelectorAll('[name=SubTotal\\[\\]]');
    var grandTotal = 0;
    Array.from(subTotals, function (subTotal, i) {
        var price = +unitPrices[i].value * +quantities[i].value;
        subTotal.value = price;
        grandTotal += price;
    });
    // Maybe you can also display the grandTotal somehwere.
} 

document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('input', calculate);
```

```css
input { max-width: 7em }
```

```html
<form action="ProvideMedicinProcess.php" class="register" method="POST">
    <table id="dataTable"  border="1">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" required="required" name="chk[]" checked="checked" /></td>
            <td><input type="datetime-local" required="required" name="VisitDate[]"></td>
            <td><input class="form-control" type="text" required="required" placeholder="Symptoms" name="Symptoms[]"></td>
            <td><input class="form-control" type="text" required="required" placeholder="Given Medicin" name="GivenMedicin[]"></td>
            <td><input class="form-control" type="text" required="required" placeholder="Unit Price" name="UnitPrice[]"></td>
            <td><input class="form-control" type="text" required="required" placeholder="Quantity" name="Quantity[]"></td>
            <td><input class="form-control" type="text" required="required" placeholder="SubTotal" readonly name="SubTotal[]" ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" required="required" name="chk[]" checked="checked" /></td>
            <td><input type="datetime-local" required="required" name="VisitDate[]"></td>
            <td><input class="form-control" type="text" required="required" placeholder="Symptoms" name="Symptoms[]"></td>
            <td><input class="form-control" type="text" required="required" placeholder="Given Medicin" name="GivenMedicin[]"></td>
            <td><input class="form-control" type="text" required="required" placeholder="Unit Price" name="UnitPrice[]"></td>
            <td><input class="form-control" type="text" required="required" placeholder="Quantity" name="Quantity[]"" ></td>
            <td><input class="form-control" type="text" required="required" placeholder="SubTotal" readonly name="SubTotal[]" ></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</form>
```

Comment: also need help for grand total :<td><input class="form-control" type="text" required="required" placeholder="GTotal" readonly name="GTotal[]" ></td>

Comment: I got it      :::::     $('input[name="MyGrandTotal"]').val(grandTotal);

Comment: Ah, you're using jQuery. If you had put that in your question, I would have used it.

Comment: is it possible to use just java without Jquery for calculating grandTotal?

Comment: I think you mean JavaScript (not Java): yes, sure that is possible: `document.querySelector('input[name=MyGrandTotal]').value = grandTotal;`

Comment: how can I print this voucher to A4 size paper?

Comment: That is a different question. If you need help with that, create a new question, provide the information you found on the subject and what you have tried, and where you are stuck with that. Tag it with `printing`, `css` and `javascript` so it will attract the right specialists.